# dates in matlab

Tags: matlab, date

In matlab, is it possible in any way to do the following:
By using

`S = DATESTR(D, 31)`

```
Number           String                Example 
31       'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'    2000-03-01 15:45:17
```

Is it possible for matlab carry out an operation of producing a string which starts and ends at specific days with a pre-defined interval.

For example, if I had data in Excel with a time vector starting at `2009-01-01 00:00:00` and finishing at `2009-10-10 10:00:00` with measurements taken every four minutes, is it possible to type this into matlab? If I'm not clear please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to read a series of dates from Excel and store it in a vector in Matlab?

Comment: I was initially attempting to do this but it seemed easier to create a vector myself seeing as I know the start and end date and also the number of minutes between the measurements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For producing an array of date strings that start/end on specific dates, with a pre-defined interval, you can do this:

Convert to a numeric date form, generate the sequence, and then convert back. For example:

```
>> datestr(datenum(datevec('2000-03-01 15:45:17')) : 1: datenum(datevec('2000-03-10 15:45:17')))

ans =

01-Mar-2000 15:45:17
02-Mar-2000 15:45:17
03-Mar-2000 15:45:17
04-Mar-2000 15:45:17
05-Mar-2000 15:45:17
06-Mar-2000 15:45:17
07-Mar-2000 15:45:17
08-Mar-2000 15:45:17
09-Mar-2000 15:45:17
10-Mar-2000 15:45:17
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you need?

```
>> dstart = datenum('2009-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
>> dend = datenum('2009-10-10 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
>> fourmins = 1/(24*60) *4;
>> dates = dstart:fourmins:dend;
>> datestrs = datestr(dates, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
>> datestrs([1,2,end-1,end],:)
ans =
2009-01-01 00:00:00
2009-01-01 00:04:00
2009-10-09 23:56:00
2009-10-10 00:00:00
```