# interpolate missing values ( with dates as sample points) in matlab

Tags: matlab, date

I am new to Matlab, stuck with understanding data types(especially cell), probably there is an elegant solution I do not know about.

I have a cell which contains other cells with dates:

```
30/09/2005
30/12/2005
...
30/09/2016
```

I have also a cell with cells containing corresponding values:

```
1
5
...
3
```

I want to interpolate those values for all days/ or working days( better for me).
What I have been thinking to do is:

1. use **datenum** to receive numbers corresponding to the dates;
2. plug these dates( now numbers), corresponding values, and all dates( now numbers) in between them, into **interp1**.

Seemed a good plan but function

```
datenum('30/12/2005')  = 13297
datenum('30/09/2016')  = 13217
```

gives numbers which can not be used as earlier date is bigger than later one.

Comment: I overlooked nice post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215172/dates-in-matlab?rq=1 I will test it now

Answer (score 0):

You can add any number of days to a datetime.

```
t = datetime('now') + days(1);
```

In addition it can give you the amount of days of a duration. Hence:

```
t0 = datetime('30/09/2005');
tEnd = datetime('30/09/2016');
durationInDays = days(tEnd - t0);
myDates(0) = t0;
for i = 2:durationInDays
   myDates(i) = myDates(i-1) + days(1);
end
```

Comment: Thanks @pablo_worker, but unfortunately, I am using 2013b Matlab, which does not have days, duration functions.